# Split field values using specific character

Tags: oracle

Please help me with this.

It is possible to split field values using a specific character? 
Here is my sample table

```
value
10uF
2K
1.0uF
200UF
```

I want it to split by this:

```
value       capacitance/resistance
 10            uF
 2             K
 1.0           uF
 200           UF
```

PS: I am using Oracle and the numbers should be separated from letters

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions is an option:

```
create table capacity (inputdata varchar2(30));

insert into capacity(inputdata) values('10uF');
insert into capacity(inputdata) values('2K');
insert into capacity(inputdata) values('1.0uF');
insert into capacity(inputdata) values('200UF');

commit;

select regexp_substr(inputdata,'^[0123456789.]*') value,
regexp_replace(inputdata,'^[0123456789.]*','') unit
from capacity
;
```

here is this example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1ee1/3)
Maybe you should improve the regular expression pattern of the number format

Regular expression functions are described [here in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions160.htm)   and on the following pages